# QT/QML reopen New Window From Main Window

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyqt5, qtquick2

I started working on QT/QML, PyQt Desktop Application. I have some basic knowledge of Qt/QML and all.

I'm trying to modify one Desktop Application already Exists.

Here is 
I've add one Button in Main Window of Application which Open another Window.

**main.qml**

```
Button {
    text: "Open Window"

    Loader{ id: pageLoader }

    onClicked: {
        console.log("Clicked")
        pageLoader.source = "testing.qml"
    }
}
```

**testing.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win1
    width: 1000;
    height: 1000;
    visible: true;
    visibility: "Maximized"
    color: "#363636";
    title: "First Window";
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Page 1"
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: pageLoader.source="";
    }
}
```

When I clicked on Button, New Window is open Successfully. But When I closed new Window and Tried to reopen, It'll not open. It just print "Clicked".

Comment: I removed some of the clutter from your example, so your example works out of the box. Please consult the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find the requirements for a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you clear the `Loader`s source, only when you close the window by clicking on the `MouseArea` it contains. If you close it with the `x`-button you don't clear it, so the loader stays active and the source stays the same.

To solve this, you can either make sure, the source changes, when ever you click the open-`Button`, by having

```
onClicked: {
    pageLoader.source = ""  // Clearing first
    pageLoader.source = "testing.qml" // Setting again
}
```

or by using the `Window`s `closing()`-signal

```
onClosing: pageLoader.source = ""
```

Comment: It Worked..!! Thanks :)

Comment: If it is correct, please do not forget to accept it as the correct answer. If it is helpful, please upvote it. If there is something missing, point it out in a comment, so the answer can be improved. This will ensure the quality of the site.